# Как поставить время задержки в анимации js

Tags: javascript

Я не разбираюсь в этом языке, но понимаю, что нужно `c.fl` что-то дописать, что будет отвечать за задержку в анимации слайдера.

```
var slideEl = $(".slide--parent");

slideEl.flickity({
  imagesLoaded: true,
  wrapAround: true,
  autoPlay: true,
  pauseAutoPlayOnHover: false

});
```

Comment: Что за такое *задержку в анимации слайдера*?

Comment: У меня так слайды ездят сменяя друг друга, вот задержу между сменой слайда

Comment: Тогда укажите, какую библиотеку для слайдов используете.

Comment: Я слабо это понимаю, но вот старница 
http://daridobro96.ru/test/block-istorii-v2.html
там только один слайдер не чего лишнего

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша библиотека называется [Flickity](https://flickity.metafizzy.co/options.html#autoplay).

После поиска в гугле и чтения документации мы узнаем, что есть свойство `autoPlay`, в котором можно установить интервал смены сладйов.

Пример на [codepen](https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/NPyWRZ).

```css
/* external css: flickity.css */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.carousel {
  background: #EEE;
}

.carousel-cell {
  width: 66%;
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: #8C8;
  border-radius: 5px;
  counter-increment: gallery-cell;
}


/* cell number */

.carousel-cell:before {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  content: counter(gallery-cell);
  line-height: 200px;
  font-size: 80px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.min.css">
<!-- JavaScript -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<h1>Flickity - autoPlay: Number</h1>

<!-- Flickity HTML init -->
<div class="carousel" data-flickity='{ "autoPlay": 500 }'>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ваша библиотека - [Flickity](https://flickity.metafizzy.co/options.html)

```
var slideEl = $(".slide--parent");

slideEl.flickity({
  imagesLoaded: true,
  wrapAround: true,
  pauseAutoPlayOnHover: false
  autoPlay: 1500, // задержка перед сменой слайда
  pauseAutoPlayOnHover: false // остановка autoplay при ховере на слайдер (изменить на true если нужно)
});
```